# Using postgis with worldwind java

Tags: java, database, postgis, spatial, worldwind

```
 I'm trying to draw a polygon in world wind java from spatial database.
```

My spatial data is in geom column in POSTGIS database.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: for the point i have tried to extract it(st_x,sty) with a sq l query and draw it in wwd.
and that's works.
for the Poly line and the  Polygon that doesn't work because i tried to make a loop to extract all the points making the poly line and add it to a array list of Positions and draw the poly line but doesn't work!!!!

Comment: I don't know worldwind, but you should be able to select the geometry and access the point array server side. You can in JTS, and I think worldwind uses JTS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe GeoServer that shows your geometry as a WMS Layer? WMS is supported in WorldWind.